# How to trigger a CALayer's animation group on a trigger?

Tags: ios

I have an animation on a CALayer which repeats indefinitely however I want to change it such that the animation is triggered by a certain timing event.

I can get it to work by removing and re-adding the animation event when the trigger occurs but this seems a bit kludgy, is there an alternative way without having to constantly remove and add the animation all the time?

Here's the code in sketch form:

```
- (void) init
{
    ….
    CALayer *sublayer = …
    [self.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
    [self createAnimationGroup];
    [sublayer addAnimation: self.animationGroup forKey:@"MyKey"];
}

- (void) createAnimationGroup
{
 CAMediaTimingFunction *defaultCurve = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    self.animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    self.animationGroup.repeatCount = 0.0f; // was previously INFINITY;
    <snip>
   NSArray *animations = @[scaleAnimation, opacityAnimation];
    self.animationGroup.animations = animations;
}


- (void) onTrigger
{
    [self.layer.sublayers[0] removeAnimationForKey:@"MyKey"];
    [self.layer.sublayers[0] addAnimation:self.animationGroup forKey:@"MyKey"];
}
```

My question is is the way I have implemented onTrigger ok, it works, but is there a way of triggering the animation directly rather than indirectly via removing and adding it?

Comment: Can you set up the animation to not repeat or removeOnCompletion and then use `runActionForKey:object:arguments:` to trigger it one time?

Comment: I've never used one of those before, I'll have to do do a bit of reading of some example use before I can try if it'll work.

Comment: It's part of the CAAction protocol, to which CAAnimation adheres.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this suggestion from Apple.  Specifically pausing and resuming an animation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW15